# How to make custom glyphicon IE compatible

Tags: css, internet-explorer, icons, glyphicons

I have the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y17550ya/) where I am combining two different spans to create a single 'user' icon in a circle.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-one-fine-empty-dot" aria-hidden="true"></span>


form-heading .glyphicon-user {
  position: relative;
    color: #9A9A98;
    font-size: 24px;
    left: 25px;
    top: -1px;
}

.glyphicon-one-fine-empty-dot:before {
    color: #9A9A98;
    content:"\20dd";
    font-size: 60px;
    position: relative;
    left: -18px;
}
```

It works fine in chrome but breaks in IE 11.
Any suggestions for how to make it work in IE too.

Thanks.

**Edit**

This is how it looks in Edge and IE 11
[image: This is how it looks in Edge and IE 11]

Comment: Can you explain how it is breaking in IE11?  Screen capture?  My first thought would be to make the glyphicon selectors position:absolute in a relative container and layer them instead of using relative spans.

Comment: @Lowkase: Just added the screentshot to the question